# How to authenticate ASP.NET Core micro service with two bearer tokens?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, asp.net-core, microservices, amazon-cognito

As my service has two consumers which have different access tokens:

1. AWS Cognito
2. Azure AD

can I authorize my service with both tokens?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we could do that, we could add more bear token authentication at the asp.net core authentication schema. Then we could use authorize policy to customize the required authentication schema.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer("AWS", options =>
    {
        // Configuration for your AWS
        // JWT tokens here
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("AAD", options =>
    {
        // Configuration for your AAD
        // JWT tokens here
    });

services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("AWS", "AAD")
            .Build();
    });
```

More details about how to use authentication schema, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes).

Comment: I found the Solution.